# Calculate the probability in R for sum of two dice rolls

Tags: r, probability, dice

I have a matrix consist of the sum of dice 1 and dice 2 OR Y = D1 + D2

```
outer(1:6, 1:6, "+")
```

The output is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9
[4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
[5,]    6    7    8    9   10   11
[6,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

How do I put it in a data frame called Y with the sum and the probability of each sum, for example:

```
Sum     pSum
2       1/36
3       2/36
4       3/36
.
.
. 
12      1/36
```

When I calculate for sum(Y$pSum), it will equal to 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a `data.frame` by converting the `outer` values to a `vector` ('Sum') and the proportion (`prop.table`) of frequencies (`table`) as 'pSum'

```
v1 <- c(m1)
data.frame(Sum = v1, pSum =  as.numeric(prop.table(table(v1))[as.character(v1)]))
```

-output

```
Sum       pSum
1    2 0.02777778
2    3 0.05555556
3    4 0.08333333
4    5 0.11111111
5    6 0.13888889
6    7 0.16666667
7    3 0.05555556
8    4 0.08333333
9    5 0.11111111
10   6 0.13888889
11   7 0.16666667
12   8 0.13888889
13   4 0.08333333
14   5 0.11111111
15   6 0.13888889
16   7 0.16666667
17   8 0.13888889
18   9 0.11111111
19   5 0.11111111
20   6 0.13888889
21   7 0.16666667
22   8 0.13888889
23   9 0.11111111
24  10 0.08333333
25   6 0.13888889
26   7 0.16666667
27   8 0.13888889
28   9 0.11111111
29  10 0.08333333
30  11 0.05555556
31   7 0.16666667
32   8 0.13888889
33   9 0.11111111
34  10 0.08333333
35  11 0.05555556
36  12 0.02777778
```

---

If we just want the summarised output

```
stack(prop.table(table(v1)))[2:1]
#    ind     values
#1    2 0.02777778
#2    3 0.05555556
#3    4 0.08333333
#4    5 0.11111111
#5    6 0.13888889
#6    7 0.16666667
#7    8 0.13888889
#9   10 0.08333333
#10  11 0.05555556
#11  12 0.02777778
```

where

```
m1 <- outer(1:6, 1:6, FUN = `+`)
```

---

Or another option is `expand.grid`

```
stack(prop.table(table(do.call(`+`, expand.grid(rep(list(1:6), 2))))))
```

Comment: How do I get the numbers on the first column NOT repeated? For example, just 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and each with an assigned probability? Right now it's listing out each outcome in the matrix.

Comment: What I expected. Thank you.